# Get manufacturer of a printer with snmp

Tags: java, printing, snmp, oid

I'm currently working on a project that involves getting values from a printer, using the SNMP Protocol. One of the tasks is to scan a specific network and get the available printers + the manufacturer.

I've tried this oid: 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.14.1.1

Now this OID works for Brother, but it won't work for Kyocera. Is there an OID that will work for (almost) all printers to get the manufacturer of the printer?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [RFC 1213](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1213.txt) you could try sysDescr(1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1 ):

sysDescr

> "A textual description of the entity.  This value
>     should include the full name and version
>     identification of the system's hardware type,
>     software operating-system, and networking
>     software.  It is mandatory that this only contain
>     printable ASCII characters."

The system section of 1213 has other interesting pieces of data like this too, like the sysObjectID (1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0):

> sysObjectID
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> The vendor's authoritative identification of the
>    network management subsystem contained in the
>    entity.  This value is allocated within the SMI
>    enterprises subtree (1.3.6.1.4.1) and provides an
>    easy and unambiguous means for determining "what
>    kind of box" is being managed.  For example, if
>    vendor "Flintstones, Inc." was assigned the
>    subtree 1.3.6.1.4.1.4242, it could assign the
>    identifier 1.3.6.1.4.1.4242.1.1 to its `Fred
>                         Router'."